# How do we distinguish between reference tag and bibliography tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are a lot of questions tagged with the tag references. But some actually fall under [bibliography](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/bibliography/info), as some disciplines/journals use the title *References* for bibliography.

And some questions are actually related to referees, as one who provides a reference.

So how should the [reference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/references/info) tag wiki should be created? The questions need to be re-tagged, according as which meaning is adopted?

Answer (score 1):

As the tag wiki for bibliography says

> Questions related to the structure, building and typesetting of a
>   bibliography comes under this tag. Bibliography is an organized
>   listing of books or a systematic, detailed description of books as
>   physical objects.

references tag excerpt may be edited to mean *references about a candidate by a reputed person* and the questions tagged with `references` that actually fall under bibliography may be changed to `bibliography` tag.